# Check overlaps of variables grouping by two columns in R

Tags: r, grouping, intervals

I want to check if some lessons of the same class have time clash. For example, consider the data:

```
class  Subject     Week_day   Start_first_lesson   End_last_lesson
1A     Calculus I  1          08:00                10:00
1A     Geometry    1          09:30                11:30
1A     Probability 1          09:50                11:50
2B     Calculus I  1          10:00                12:00
2B     Geometry    2          14:00                16:00
```

Grouping by the variables "class" and "Week_day", I would like the following output:

```
class  Subject      Week_day  Start_first_lesson   End_last_lesson   Conflict   Subject_with_conflict
1A     Calculus I   1         08:00                10:00             Yes        Geometry, Probability
1A     Geometry     1         09:30                11:30             Yes        Calculus I, Probability
1A     Probability  1         09:50                11:50             Yes        Calculus I, Geometry
2B     Calculus I   1         10:00                12:00             No
2B     Geometry     2         14:00                16:00             No
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check for `foverlaps` from `data.table` grouped by 'class', 'Week_day'

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I will check that!

Comment: I don't think `foverlaps` will work, because I don't know how many subjects I have for each class and Week_day, and hence I don't know how to separate the data for merging they later with foverlaps.